# Matplotlib boxplot x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

It's easier to ask this with a figure. At the moment i obtain the following boxplot graph using matplotlib:
[image]

Is there a way to obtain a figure like that, but with each box in a position coherent with the corresponding x-axis number (like in a normal scatter plot, but with boxes instead of points)?

At the moment the numbers on the x-axis are added by means of the `labels=` argument.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to specify the `positions` argument to the [`boxplot` constructor](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.boxplot([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]], positions=[2,4,5.5])
```

[image]

By default it uses the values `[1, 2, ..., n]` but you can specify a different x position for each bar and the xticks will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will it work even with floating point values (like the ones in the example)?

Comment: @FMarazzi Yes. I updated the example to demonstrate that.